# Node module canvas gives electron-rebuild errors

Tags: node.js, canvas, node-modules

I am trying to build canvas node-module for my project. I install canvas 2.6.1 and when I run "./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild", it fails and gives MSBuild errors.

Can you also explain what electron-rebuild does?